# How to define with Lombok Date And Collections immutable?

Tags: java, immutability, lombok

I am in a dilemma with lombok, those who know this tool know that it is very easy to declare the getters and setters but when it comes to Dates and Collections, how can we declare them immutable?

Thx & Kind regards!

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. You *can* declare getters and setters for Dates and Collections as simple as you do it for other types, but you can't customise getters/setters or any other autogenerated code. "Making a collection immutable" is too broad and requires some knowledge about the structure.

Comment: How would Lombok know which immutability you prefer? How to make immutable your collection class `MySuperArrayList`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lombok provides [@Wither](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Wither) that allows somehow to ease creation of immutable objects. However, it doesn't cover the cases that you mentioned.

You will have to manage immutability of the objects yourself, and use Lombok for all other situations.

Also, this is an example how to implement `ImmutableObject` with `Date` and `Collection`:

```
public final class ImmutableObject {
    private final Collection<String> collection;
    private final Date date;

    public ImmutableObject(final Collection<String> options, final Date createdAt) {
        this.collection = ImmutableList.copyOf(options); // guava's immutable list
        this.date = new Date(date); // must be copied to prevent caller from modifying it
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return new Date(date); // Date is mutable
    }

    public Collection<String> getCollection() {
        return collection; // already immutable copy
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, @Wither is experimental for that i didn't use it. Thanks you

Comment: @Matheus `@Wither` is experimental and I use it since its very beginning. I'm pretty sure, it won't ever go away or get changed in an incompatible way and I'm also sure, there was noch such proposal -- ever. `+++` However, I'd strongly suggest to drop the obsolete `Date` in favor of the `java.time.*` classes, which are immutable and much better in many aspects.

Comment: Thank you very much @maaartinus for your response, but I have decided to remove lombok from my project for several reasons. I prefer to have complete control of my objects!

Comment: @Matheus Your choice makes me sad, but it's your choice. I can't really imagine doing Java without Lombok as it saves so much boilerplate. Using delombok, I can see that's about factor 1.4 and that's really a lot.